# Parse String to Tokens in Unix

Tags: unix, sed, grep, replace

I want to parse a string (using awk/sed/grep):

```
"EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD"
```

And result should be:

```
EffTimeStamp="20110203-210000"
InputCtxNm="Forigen Exchange Today"
RunType="EOD"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a couple different substitutions, but `sed` can do this.

```
sed 's/^"//; s/=/="/g; s/#/"\n/g'
```

e.g.

```
% echo '"EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD"' | 
    sed 's/^"//;s/=/="/g;s/#/"\n/g'
EffTimeStamp="20110203-210000"
InputCtxNm="Forigen Exchange Today"
RunType="EOD"
```

Answer (score 0):

What shell are you using? For bash, you can write

```
str="EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD"
oifs=$IFS
IFS="#"
set -- $str
IFS=$oifs
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

outputs

```
EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000
InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today
RunType=EOD
```

If you don't want to use the positional parameters, you can store the values as an array:

```
arr=($str)
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

or and **awk** solution

```
 echo "EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD" \
 |  awk -F# -v OFS="\n" '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) printf("%s%s", $i, (i==NF ? "\n" : OFS)) }'
```

**output**

```
EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000
InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today
RunType=EOD
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Shelter : How to print, if there is varying list of parameter ?
e.g "EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD#RegionName=US#InstruID=9999....."

Answer (score 0):

One simple way with `perl` modifying `$/` (Input Record Separator) and `$\` (Output Record Separator):

```
echo -e "EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD" | 
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $/ = q[#]; $\ = qq[\n] }'
```

Output:

```
EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#
InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#
RunType=EOD
```